# Procurar por mais de um valor na mesma coluna?

Tags: mysql

A tabela tem os campos (id_exame, id_paciente, data_exame, ressultado) e tem exames desde 2010 até hoje. 
Gostaria de trazer os registros dos pacientes que fizeram exames em 2011, 2012 e 2015 por exemplo.
Tem que trazer os registros nesses anos, ou seja, se fez em 2011,2012 e 2015.
É possivel trazer os registros?

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM
    nome_tabela 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM data_exame) = 2015
     AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM data_exame) = 2016;
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica se isso te atende:

**2 anos**

```
SELECT id, data_exame, resultado FROM Minha_tabela where YEAR(data_exame) = 2015 OR YEAR(data_exame) = 2016;
```

**3 anos**

```
SELECT id, data_exame, resultado FROM Minha_tabela where YEAR(data_exame) = 2014 OR YEAR(data_exame) = 2015 OR YEAR(data_exame) = 2016;
```

Para cada ano você adiciona um '`OR`' e não um '`AND`'.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usaro `OR` como foi dito mas também pode fazer assim com `AND`:

```
WHERE YEAR(data_exame) >= 2015 AND YEAR(data_exame) <= 2016
```

ou então pode usar o `BETWEEN`:

```
WHERE YEAR(data_exame) BETWEEN 2015 AND 2016
```